Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 Very slow start and will not resume at all after suspend
I have a new install of Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop, and the start up time is very very slow.
My Motherboard is the ASUS Z97-WS.
In addition, resume is non existent after suspend.
My PC just hangs until I do a hard reset.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Apps slow to start after reboot
My system runs the standard Ubuntu 24.04 with X11/GNOME (previously had same issue with 23.10) and the applications were very slow to open after starting the machine for the first ~2 minutes. Problem appears to be related to xdg-desktop-portal.

So one solution for me was booting the machine and do nothing for a few minutes. After that it worked as normal.

Another solution is getting rid of xdg-desktop-portal as suggested here, or mask it instead as I did. (I don't know what the consequences of purging it are.)

My solution was masking it instead of purging. Note the command doesn't use sudo and has flag --user:


$ systemctl is-enabled --user xdg-desktop-portal
static

$ systemctl mask --user xdg-desktop-portal
Created symlink /home/daniel/.config/systemd/user/xdg-desktop-portal.service → /dev/null.

$ systemctl is-enabled --user xdg-desktop-portal
masked

To revert the command: $ systemctl unmask --user xdg-desktop-portal
Side effects (there could be others): Can't download files in Firefox.
In my case apps open again quickly after rebooting. But because I need to frequently download PDF files I unmasked the service and now just wait about two to three minutes after starting my machine before working.
Problems resuming after suspend
I don't know about the suspend/resume issue you're having. 
In my case the laptop wakes up on its own a few seconds after suspend.
